# Laravel - Nexmo "Please provide Nexmo API credentials" Error

Tags: php, laravel, sms, laravel-5.8, vonage

I want send send SMS with laravel-Nexmo. I already configure all the settings. But when i try to send a SMS it gives this error

> Please provide Nexmo API credentials. Possible combinations: api_key +
>   api_secret, api_key + signature_secret, private_key + application_id,
>   api_key + api_secret + private_key + application_id, api_key +
>   signature_secret + private_key + application_id

I added nexmo api_key & secret_key in services.php , .env file and nexmo.php 
I also added this;
`curl.cainfo="C:\xampp\apache\bin\cacert.pem"` in php.ini file

What is the reason for this error and how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: If you cache your config, make sure to re-cache it whenever you modify the config or .env files. `php artisan config:clear` to clear it, or `php artisan config:cache` to clear and cache it.

Comment: I did not clear or cache the config. what i suppose to do?

Comment: Hey did you every fix this? I'm running into the same error and have added NEXMO_KEY and NEXMO_SECRET to my .env file

Answer (score 1):

> I already configure all the settings.

What exact settings did you configure? The error means that the library could not determine an appropriate set of credentials to use for Nexmo.

If you are sending an SMS, all you need to set is `NEXMO_KEY` and `NEXMO_SECRET`. I would try setting just those two environment options and see if you get the same error. If you are using request signing by setting `NEXMO_SIGNATURE_SECRET`, I would disable that for the time being just to check that sending a base SMS works.

Once you update your settings, I would make sure that the cache is cleared using `artisan config:clear` to clear the cache, which should allow the settings to be picked up on the next page load.

Comment: Thats why i said i already set that. I set the NEXMO_KEY and NEXMO_SECRET

Comment: There are multiple settings, which is why I asked. Did you try clearing the config cache to make sure it is being picked up properly?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and was able to fix it.

**Cause**

It looks to me like laravel/nexmo-notification-channel has been updated, but Laravel itself hasn't (yet).

According to the Laravel [6.x] pull request:

> `composer require laravel/nexmo-notification-channel`
>
> This will also install the nexmo/laravel package. This package includes its own configuration file. You can use the NEXMO_KEY and
>   NEXMO_SECRET environment variables to set your Nexmo public and secret
>   key.

https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/5519/files?short_path=7c04c15#diff-7c04c1591e2821d381785df56ebd70af

**Solution**
It was easy, just copy this new nexmo.php config file into your config folder: https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-laravel/blob/master/config/nexmo.php

As long as you have the NEXMO_KEY and NEXMO_SECRET set in your .env file, it should now work.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Laravel 8 and faced the same issue. Then I realize that I was adding

```
  NEXMO_KEY=your key here 
  NEXMO_SECRET=your secret here
```

to `.env.example` file. I just added it to `.env` file and re-config the cache by `php artisan config:cache`
Now it's working.

Note: you should get your `api_key` and `secret` rom vonage.com